# Trying to Modify a Script to Take Timestamp Date Format Instead of %Y-%m-%d Format [Python]

Tags: python, csv, datetime

Pulling dates from a csv in Timestamp format (ex. 1504159200).
I'm plugging these into a script suited for Y-m-d format.

[The code is a massive LSTM script so hopefully the original lines and what I tried on them will suffice]

```
startDate = 1504159200  
endDate = 1519974000
```

Original lines without modifying...

```
sd = datetime.strptime(startDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
ed = datetime.strptime(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "stocks.py", line 91, in <module>
p, n = Main(['last_vix_92_18.csv', '1504159200', '1519974000', 'D'])
File "stocks.py", line 78, in Main
P = sp.PredictDate(args[1], args[2], predPrd)
File "/home/eagle/predict/dragon/pythonml-master/Stocks/StockPredictor.py", line 282, in PredictDate
ts = DateRange(startDate, endDate, period)[::-1]
File "/home/eagle/predict/dragon/pythonml-master/Stocks/StockPredictor.py", line 30, in DateRange
sd = datetime.strptime(startDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 343, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '1504159200' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

I've tried modifying the code thusly with the following error below.

```
sd = datetime(int(startDate)).timestamp()
ed = datetime(int(endDate)).timestamp()  

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "stocks.py", line 91, in <module>
p, n = Main(['last_vix_92_18.csv', '1504159200', '1519974000', 'D'])
File "stocks.py", line 78, in Main
P = sp.PredictDate(args[1], args[2], predPrd)
File "/home/eagle/predict/dragon/pythonml-master/Stocks/StockPredictor.py", line 284, in PredictDate
ts = DateRange(startDate, endDate, period)[::-1]
File "/home/eagle/predict/dragon/pythonml-master/Stocks/StockPredictor.py", line 31, in DateRange
sd = datetime(int(startDate)).timestamp()
TypeError: Required argument 'month' (pos 2) not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=re#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.fromtimestamp(1504159200)  # datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 31, 2, 0)
datetime.fromtimestamp(1519974000)  # datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 2, 2, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I wasn't able to find 'fromtimestamp' anywhere. I looked for a while, I swear. The code that ended up working for my case is slightly different. Just one 'datetime'.     sd = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(startDate))
    ed = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(endDate))

Comment: @Renoldus That's because you must have already imported the `datetime` submodule... Updating the example.

Comment: I see. Does that work for any module? Just double up and you don't have to import it? I learn everyday.

Comment: @Renoldus Not necessarily... package structure differs across packages.

Comment: I can't believe I found my solution in this post, lolz, ```datetime.fromtimestamp``` worked like a charm!